# Update Typo3 9.5.27 with Composer to 10.4

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

i tried updating a Typo3 Website running version 9.5.27 in Composer mode to at least version ^10.4.

i updated the composer.json from

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
    ],
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^5.5.5",
        "typo3/minimal": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-about": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-redirects": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^9.5"
    },
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure",
            "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    }
}
```

to the 10.4 version

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
    ],
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^6.0.0@beta",
        "typo3/cms-about": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-backend": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-core": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-dashboard": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-filelist": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-fluid": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-frontend": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-install": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-recordlist": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^10.4"
        
    },
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure",
            "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    }
}
```

after that i ran a `composer update`and everything went fine. Now when i try to login it tells me that im missing tables in my database. i obviously forgot to update the database aswell, but where do i do that? i tried following [this](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/Upgrade/InstallTheNewSource/Index.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When updating TYPO3 to a new major version, you need to run the [Upgrade Wizards](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/Upgrade/UseTheUpgradeWizard/Index.html) and [Database Analyzer](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/Upgrade/RunTheDatabaseAnalyzer/Index.html) in the install tool. These will convert data/files and create/alter/remove database tables and fields as needed. You should also check the other steps in that documentation.

Comment: i did that. the Database Analyzer says "Database Schema is up to date. Good job!". The Upgrade Wizards are done aswell. I doublechecked by running ```./vendor/bin/typo3 upgrade:run```

Comment: And you're still getting the error? Does it say which tables are missing?

Comment: i did a clean composer install of a 10.4.17 version and checked the database, then i checked the database of the fresh 9.5 version. when i try to log in it tells me that im missing the table "cache_hash". This table exists on the 10.4.17 Version but not on the upgraded 10.4.17 version

Comment: to be exact. after upgrading from 9.5 to 10.4.17 and logging it i get this error: `
Oops, an error occurred!
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `content` FROM `cache_hash` WHERE (`identifier` = ?) AND (`expires` >= ?)' with params ["d07b003d9fce07cd551ada22027bf881", 1626341203]: Table 'complan4.cache_hash' doesn't exist`

Comment: `cache_hash` is a default table. If it doesn't exist, it should be added by the Database Analyzer. Can you check in your database if it's there?

Comment: in the upgraded 10.4.17 site theres no chache_hash table, however i see a cf_cache_hash table together with a couple other cf_ tables. im not sure but i think they are coming from the original 9.5 version